# cannot use sudo after using sudo passwd root

Tags: 14.04, sudo, root

My System problem detected when I tried `sudo passwd root` in my ubuntu.

I changed my `root` password by  using the below command.

```
sudo passwd root
```

Now my system password changed, after this i could not use `sudo` now.when I try to use `sudo -i` I am getting error messages below.

```
sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin 'sudoers_policy'
sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be only be writable by owner
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

Comment: your user password is different then the Unix `root` password

Comment: see Askubuntu post[How do I reset a lost administrative password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
su
passwd -l root
exit
```

Once made this, try again `sudo -i`

Comment: how should i execute these commands..when i try `su` it asks me password..

Comment: Yes, you may need to type the root password, the same password that you typed twice when prompted after executing the `sudo passwd root` command

Comment: Did it worked? If worked, please accept my answer else say me what fails.

Comment: Sorry @Helio not worked..i changed my OS i couldn't wait for a long time.

Comment: Ok, sorry. However, if do you have any doubt, please ask on this site.